# How to reach my controller from code-behind

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, geometry

I have this `Circle ProgressBar` that responds to my `Slider` value changed:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="530,303,114,303">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="153" Width="155">
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="8" Percentage="100" />
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar Name="circleVale" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="#026873" StrokeThickness="8" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" Value="0" Width="200" Margin="597,185,227,495" />
    <Label Name="lblCircleProgress" Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" Margin="698,344,284,343" Foreground="White"
```

How can I change this value in the code-behind?
I tried to give this control a `name` property (Name="circleVale") but for some reason I cannot reach it in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your circleVale control should be accessible in the code behind, but apart from that, i think using SetCurrentValue will leave the binding in place.

Can you change any other property of the progressbar from code?

Answer (score 0):

You have the property Percentage of your CircularProgressBar  named "circleVale" bound to the slider's Value. In order to change them from the code behind try to set a depdendency property :

```
    public int SliderValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SliderValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SliderValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SliderValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SliderValue", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private void btnChangeSliderValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SliderValue = 70;
    }
```

Set the DataContext of your Window in the constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

And this can be an example for your XAML:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding SliderValue}" Width="200"/>
        <Button Click="btnChangeSliderValue_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Change slider value" Margin="5,10"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This way you don't need to access the slider using its name. Using binding is easier and step by step you can reach MVVM.